# mysql join to exclude missing entries

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and I want to display all records from the first table where the field that joins them is not present in the second table.

```
$sql = "SELECT d.*,t.id from `donations` d
JOIN `teams` t
ON d.teamid = t.id
 WHERE t.id IS NULL";
```

In other words I want to join donations and teams. But I want to retrieve only the records from donations where the team field is not present in the teams table.

The above displays zero records and is not doing the trick.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I recommend reading about left and right joins. It could be the answer to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT d.*,t.id from `donations` d
LEFT OUTER JOIN `teams` t
ON d.teamid = t.id
 WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub query.

```
select * from donations
where teamid not in (
    select id from teams
)
```

That should select all donations which has a teamid which is not present in the teams table.